# Create a plot showing the number of items released by year

Tags: r

Trying to create a plot showing the number of items (ex. pop_songs) released by year from a dataframe I have (ex. Music_Charts).

I have a year released column in my dataframe and can use that as the x-variable, but I don't know what I would use for the y-variable to show the boxplot since I have the Top 500 Ranked songs on the dataframe.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Music_Charts)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Music_Charts, 20))`.

Comment: Also, what type of plot do you want? A bar plot?

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on your very general question, if you have a data frame column with the years for each song, you can easily get the count for that column using `table`.

`table(dataframe$year_released)`

That should give you the number of entries for every year, then you can plot them (i'm guessing that's what you need)